# Greatest n per group reference with intervals in R or SQL

Tags: sql, r, memory-management, greatest-n-per-group, data.table

I have described my (non-trivial) problem described below. This is my first post, now in a modified version. Any inputs or proposed solutions would be helpful.

There are several dimensions to this: determination of an **optimal solution of small scale problem** (several suggestions already below), **time** (data.table solution below seems to check the box) and **memory management**. The problem is about tags that enumerated in one table and represented by clusters in another(same cluster if within 30bp on same strand).

The challenge boils do to determining an efficient procedure of allocating a given tag to the appropriate interval. We are dealing with genomic data which means thats that tag coordinates are determined by start position, end position (=start position + 1), chromosome (25 values in full data set) and strand (position is on either the plus or minus strand over the double-stranded DNA). Clusters are thus non-overlapping on the same strand, but cluster coordinates can overlap if their intervals are on different strands complicates things.

This is a modified version of my post from Jan 9th, that better encapsulates the inherent difficulty of the problem. A fast solution that solves the small scale problem is shown later.
If anyone want to work on the full dataset, let me know.
 Many thanks in advance!

Regards,

Nick Clark

**Background**
The issue involves intervals and greatest n per group. I have two tables containing clustered gene coordinates (clusters) and the input data (tags). The clusters table contains the summed tags from each covered non-overlapping interval on the same strand from the tags table. The full clusters table has 1.6 mln rows. The tags table about 4 mln rows, so the solution should ideally be vectorised. See below for some sample data. The setting is a data set on transcription initiation sites (CAGE) for human.

As I am working in R, I am look for a solution based in R or SQL. I have made previous unsuccessful attempts both via the plyr and sqldf packages in R.

**The Challenge**
What I am is missing is a row in the clustered table identifying the start coordinate from the input data table associated with the largest tag contribution.

Note that 
1) clusters from different strands can have overlapping coordinates,
2) chr / chr_clst can take on 25 different values (not shown in example),
3) a solution needs to account for both strand and chr / chr_clst.

**My Ideal Solution:**
Vectorized R code or improvement on SQL statement below. A version of the solution below, that accounts for the memory problem would do the trick. As would an improved sql statement that efficiently determines the appropriate row from the clusters table.

**Status so far**
Here is the apparently best solution so far. **Hat tip and cool points to user1935457 for the code and to mnel for subsequent suggested modification**. The snag here is that moving from the toy example to the fill scale tables crashes both R (and R Studio) due to excessive demands on memory.

```
# Convert sample data provided in question
clusters <- as.data.table(clusters)
tags <- as.data.table(tags)

# Rename chr and strand for easier joining
setnames(clusters, c("chr_clst", "strand_clst"), c("chr", "strand"))

# Set key on each table for next step
setkey(clusters, chr, strand)
setkey(tags, chr, strand)

# Merge on the keys
tmp <- merge(clusters, tags, by = c("chr", "strand"))

# Find index (in merged table, tmp) of largest tag_count in each
# group subject to start_clst <= end <= end_clst
idx <- tmp[between(end, start_clst, end_clst),
       list(IDX=.I[which.max(tag_count)]),
       by=list(chr, start_clst,end_clst,strand)]$IDX

# Get those rows from merged table
tmp[idx]
```

I initially created a basic SQL query using the sqldf package in R (this version finds the              max and not the coordinate associated with the max). The query takes forever to run, despite placing (hopefully) appropriate indices on both tables.

```
output_tablename <- sqldf(c(
"create index ai1 on clusters(chr_clst, start_clst, end_clst, strand_clst)",
"create index ai2 on tags(chr, start, end, strand)",
"select a.chr_clst, a.start_clst, a.end_clst, a.strand_clst, sum(b.tags)
from main.clusters a
inner join main.tags b on a.chr_clst=b.chr and a.strand_clst = b.strand 
and b.end between a.start_clst and a.end_clst
group by a.chr_clst, a.start_clst, a.end_clst, a.strand_clst
order by a.chr_clst, a.start_clst, a.end_clst, a.strand_clst"
))
```

**Table structure**
clusters: chr_clst, start_clst, end_clst, strand_clst, tags_clst.
tags: chr, start, end, strand, tag_count.

**Sample Data in R format**
Let me know if anyone want to work on the full dataset, let me know.

clusters:

```
chr_clst <- c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1")
start_clst <- c(568911, 569233, 569454, 569793, 569877, 569926, 569972, 570048, 570166, 713987)
end_clst <- c(568941, 569256, 569484, 569803, 569926, 569952, 569973, 570095, 570167, 714049)
strand_clst <- c("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "+", "+", "+", "-")
tags_clst <- c(37, 4, 6, 3, 80, 25, 1, 4, 1, 46)

clusters <- data.frame(cbind(chr_clst, start_clst, end_clst, strand_clst, tags_clst))
clusters$start_clst <- as.numeric(as.character(clusters$start_clst))
clusters$end_clst <- as.numeric(as.character(clusters$end_clst))
clusters$tags_clst <- as.numeric(as.character(clusters$tags_clst))
rm(chr_clst, start_clst, end_clst, start_clst, strand_clst, tags_clst)
```

tags:

```
chr <- c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1")

start <- c(568911, 568912, 568913, 568913, 568914, 568916, 568917, 568918, 568929, 
568929, 568932, 568933, 568935, 568937, 568939, 568940, 568940, 569233, 569247, 
569255, 569454, 569469, 569471, 569475, 569483, 569793, 569802, 569877, 569880, 
569887, 569889, 569890, 569891, 569893, 569894, 569895, 569895, 569896, 569897, 
569898, 569898, 569899, 569900, 569900, 569901, 569901, 569903, 569905, 569906, 
569907, 569907, 569908, 569908, 569909, 569910, 569910, 569911, 569911, 569912, 
569914, 569914, 569915, 569916, 569917, 569918, 569919, 569920, 569920, 569925, 
569926, 569936, 569938, 569939, 569939, 569940, 569941, 569941, 569942, 569942, 
569943, 569944, 569948, 569948, 569951, 569972, 570048, 570057, 570078, 570094, 
570166, 713987, 713989, 713995, 714001, 714001, 714007, 714008, 714010, 714011, 
714011, 714011, 714013, 714015, 714015, 714017, 714018, 714019, 714023, 714025, 
714029, 714034, 714034, 714037, 714038, 714039, 714039, 714040, 714042, 714048, 
714048)

end <- c(568912, 568913, 568914, 568914, 568915, 568917, 568918, 568919, 568930, 
568930, 568933, 568934, 568936, 568938, 568940, 568941, 568941, 569234, 569248,
569256, 569455, 569470, 569472, 569476, 569484, 569794, 569803, 569878, 569881, 
569888, 569890, 569891, 569892, 569894, 569895, 569896, 569896, 569897, 569898, 
569899, 569899, 569900, 569901, 569901, 569902, 569902, 569904, 569906, 569907, 
569908, 569908, 569909, 569909, 569910, 569911, 569911, 569912, 569912, 569913, 
569915, 569915, 569916, 569917, 569918, 569919, 569920, 569921, 569921, 569926, 
569927, 569937, 569939, 569940, 569940, 569941, 569942, 569942, 569943, 569943, 
569944, 569945, 569949, 569949, 569952, 569973, 570049, 570058, 570079, 570095, 
570167, 713988, 713990, 713996, 714002, 714002, 714008, 714009, 714011, 714012, 
714012, 714012, 714014, 714016, 714016, 714018, 714019, 714020, 714024, 714026, 
714030, 714035, 714035, 714038, 714039, 714040, 714040, 714041, 714043, 714049, 
714049)

strand <- c("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-")

tag_count <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 2, 8, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2)

tags <- data.frame(cbind(chr, start, end, strand, tag_count))    
tags$start <- as.numeric(as.character(tags$start))
tags$end <- as.numeric(as.character(tags$end))
tags$tag_count <- as.numeric(as.character(tags$tag_count))
rm(chr, start, end, strand, tag_count)
```

Comment: Please also post expected results, and ideally the code that you have tried.

Comment: Note that sqldf defaults to SQLite, not MySQL, although it does also support MySQL and will do so automatically if you have RMySQL loaded.  It also supports PostgreSQL which does have `partition by`.  Use the `sqldf` `drv=` argument or the `sqldf.driver` option or just load RPostgreSQL before sqldf and it will notice it.  See https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#12._How_does_one_use_sqldf_with_PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Andrie Regarding previous work I tried the following using the sqldf package with default settings. While it works it is incredibly slow: human_brain2 <- sqldf(c( "create index ai1 on human_brain1(chr, start, end, strand)", "create index ai2 on human_brian_tags(chr, start, end, strand)", "select a.chr_clst, a.start_clst, a.end_clst, a.strand_clst, sum(b.tags) from clusters a inner join tags b on a.chr_clst=b.chr and b.end between a.start_clst and a.end_clst group by a.chr_clst, a.start_clst, a.end_clst, a.strand_clst"))

Comment: @G. Grothendieck: Thanks for that. I have previously mainly worked with MSSQL, so there is a bit of a learning curve. I am convinced that some combination of a self join and a partition by would do the trick while also be more efficient. But at this stage I was rather hoping to avoid having to invest time on a new DMBS. Cheers!

Comment: Note that your sqldf is actually not using the indexes you created and that is probably why its slow.  See examples 4h and 4i on the sqldf home page and particularly note that after you create the index you must refer to the table as main.myTable and not myTable so that it uses the version with the indexes and does not try to grab it from your R workspace.  http://sqldf.googlecode.com

Comment: @G. Grothendieck: That is a good and valid point! This was a careless omission on my part. I have actually done this previously and it did improve performance. Having said that, I ran the query on the full, indexed tables with 4 mln and 1.6 mln rows. I switched it off as it was still running after eight hours. So I am thinking there must be more to it than that. Thanks again for your input!

Comment: You can debug your queries by placing `explain query plan` prior to the select statement.  See http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html .

Comment: @G. Grothendieck: Maybe I am missing something, but I don't know how to impose primary keys inside the confines of sqldf. Thinking that doing so, might solve the issue. Do you know if that's possible. Not clear from http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/.

Comment: This will display the create statement it uses: `sqldf(c("select * from BOD", "select * from sqlite_master"))` and then you can do this (the actual computation would be the third component of the vector argument): `sqldf(c("create table BODpk (Time real primary key, demand real)", "insert into BODpk select * from BOD"))` .  This is also getting sufficiently complex that you might alternately want to go directly to RSQLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt with the `data.table` package:

```
# Convert sample data provided in question
clusters <- as.data.table(clusters)
tags <- as.data.table(tags)

# Rename chr and strand for easier joining
setnames(clusters, c("chr_clst", "strand_clst"), c("chr", "strand"))

# Set key on each table for next step
setkey(clusters, chr, strand)
setkey(tags, chr, strand)

# Merge on the keys
tmp <- merge(clusters, tags, by = c("chr", "strand"))

# Find index (in merged table, tmp) of largest tag_count in each
# group subject to start_clst <= end <= end_clst
idx <- tmp[between(end, start_clst, end_clst),
           list(IDX=.I[which.max(tag_count)]),
           by=list(chr, start_clst,end_clst,strand)]$IDX

# Get those rows from merged table
tmp[idx]
```

Output of last line:

```
     chr strand start_clst end_clst tags_clst  start    end tag_count
 1: chr1      -     569926   569952        25 569942 569943         4
 2: chr1      -     713987   714049        46 714011 714012         4
 3: chr1      +     568911   568941        37 568940 568941         8
 4: chr1      +     569233   569256         4 569255 569256         2
 5: chr1      +     569454   569484         6 569471 569472         2
 6: chr1      +     569793   569803         3 569793 569794         2
 7: chr1      +     569877   569926        80 569925 569926         5
 8: chr1      +     569972   569973         1 569972 569973         1
 9: chr1      +     570048   570095         4 570048 570049         1
10: chr1      +     570166   570167         1 570166 570167         1
```

### Edit

Based on the memory issues discussed in comments below, here's another attempt. I use the `intervals` package to find overlapping intervals between the two tables.  You could also explore parallelizing the `for` loop to gain speed.

```
require(data.table)
require(intervals)
clusters <- data.table(clusters)
tags <- data.table(tags)

#  Find all unique combinations of chr and strand...
setkey(clusters, chr_clst, strand_clst)
setkey(tags, chr, strand)

unique.keys <- unique(rbind(clusters[, key(clusters), with=FALSE],
                            tags[, key(tags), with=FALSE], use.names=FALSE))

# ... and then work on each pair individually to avoid creating
# enormous objects in memory
result.list <- vector("list", nrow(unique.keys))
for(i in seq_len(nrow(unique.keys))) {
  tmp.clst <- clusters[unique.keys[i]]
  tmp.tags <- tags[unique.keys[i]]

  # Keep track of each row for later
  tmp.clst[, row.id := seq_len(nrow(tmp.clst))]
  tmp.tags[, row.id := seq_len(nrow(tmp.tags))]

  # Use intervals package to find all overlapping [start, end] 
  # intervals between the two tables
  clst.intervals <- Intervals(tmp.clst[, list(start_clst, end_clst)],
                              type = "Z")
  tags.intervals <- Intervals(tmp.tags[, list(start, end)],
                              type = "Z")
  rownames(tags.intervals) <- tmp.tags$row.id

  # This goes to C++ code in intervals package; 
  # I didn't spend too much time looking over how it works
  overlaps <- interval_overlap(tags.intervals,
                               clst.intervals,
                               check_valid = FALSE)

  # Retrieve rows from clusters table with overlaps and add a column
  # indicating which intervals in tags table they overlapped with
  matches <- lapply(as.integer(names(overlaps)), function(n) {
    ans <- tmp.clst[overlaps[[n]]]
    ans[, match.in.tags := n]
  })

  # List back to one table...
  matches <- rbindlist(matches)

  # ... and join each match from tags to its relevant row from tags
  setkey(matches, match.in.tags)
  setkey(tmp.tags, row.id)

  # add the rows for max of tag_count by start_clst and
  # end_clst from this particular unique key to master list...
  result.list[[i]] <- tmp.tags[matches][, .SD[which.max(tag_count)],
                                        by = list(start_clst, end_clst)]
}

# and concatenate master list into none table,
# getting rid of the helper columns
rbindlist(result.list)[, c("row.id", "row.id.1") := NULL][]
```

The last line gives:

```
    start_clst end_clst  chr strand  start    end tag_count chr_clst strand_clst tags_clst
 1:     569926   569952 chr1      - 569942 569943         4     chr1           -        25
 2:     713987   714049 chr1      - 714011 714012         4     chr1           -        46
 3:     568911   568941 chr1      + 568940 568941         8     chr1           +        37
 4:     569233   569256 chr1      + 569255 569256         2     chr1           +         4
 5:     569454   569484 chr1      + 569471 569472         2     chr1           +         6
 6:     569793   569803 chr1      + 569793 569794         2     chr1           +         3
 7:     569877   569926 chr1      + 569925 569926         5     chr1           +        80
 8:     569972   569973 chr1      + 569972 569973         1     chr1           +         1
 9:     570048   570095 chr1      + 570048 570049         1     chr1           +         4
10:     570166   570167 chr1      + 570166 570167         1     chr1           +         1
```

Comment: `clusters[tags][end %between% c(start_clst, end_clst)][,.SD[which.max(tag_count)], by=list(chr, start_clst,end_clst,strand)]` avoids having to manually create `tmp` and `idx`.

Comment: @user1935457: Thanks for doing that. I am not familiar with the data.table package, but looks somewhat similar to plyr. I ran your code twice and in both instances R Studio suffers a "fatal error" during the merging of the keys! Not knowing the package I would appreciate any thoughts you might have on that. Thanks.

Comment: @Nick Clark: R Studio fatal error as in the whole program crashes or you get an error message called "fatal error" in the program?  If the former, does it work in default R without R Studio? If the latter, what is the output of `traceback()` after the error happens? Other info that might be useful is the output of `sessionInfo()` and `package.Version("data.table")` and whether the error is happening on the sample data you provided in the question or on your full dataset.

Comment: @ user1935457: R studio displays an error message with a picture of an exploding bomb. Default R, while less graphic, also crashes. You can find a screenshot from default R in the following links: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14954362/Crash%20in%20Default%20R%20-%20Nick%20Clark.png. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14954362/Crash%20in%20R%20Studio%20-%20Nick%20Clark.png. It looks like a memory issue. I selected option four (see screendump) and the software closed. Also see this link for sessionInfo. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14954362/RStudio%20-%20session%20info%20-%20Nick%20Clark.png.

Comment: @user1935457: Also package_version("data.table") results in an error message "Error: invalid version specification ‘data.table’". Not good news I'm afraid. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: These links should work: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14954362/Crash%20in%20Default%20R%20-%20Nick%20Clark.png, http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14954362/Crash%20in%20R%20Studio%20-%20Nick%20Clark.png, http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14954362/RStudio%20-%20session%20info%20-%20Nick%20Clark.png

Comment: Does the alternate syntax in mnel's comment work?  (Replace everything after the two setkey commands with the code in that comment)  SessionInfo screenshot showed data.table version, and everything seems up to date.  Is this error on the same small subset of your data as in the question or on the whole dataset?

Comment: I have been meaning to check, but unfortunately won't get time to do so before tonight. I will post back with the outcome then. Many thanks.

Comment: @NickClark The error for `package_version("data.table")` is correct. You get the same error for `package_version("sqldf")` and `package_version("base")`. See `?package_version`. `packageVersion("data.table")` is the correct command :) I see how user1935457's comment had a dot which sent you on the wrong track. Most people use `sessionInfo()` then we see the versions of everything loaded in case something is odd there.

Comment: @NickClark In terms of the RStudio crash, it's the second time recently I heard of a crash in RStudio. Please try in a console outside of RStudio and see if it works there. That has worked for others. Then we can go from there.

Comment: @Matthew Dowle: He already tried it in the default R interface.  See the first screenshot linked in comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231737/greatest-n-per-group-reference-with-intervals-in-r-or-sql/14250433#comment19781343_14250433).  I don't know what caused the segfault in that screenshot, but I think I got an integer overflow in `vecseq.c` using dummy data somewhat similar to how he described his dataset.

Comment: @user1935457 Many thanks for the reproducible report on datatable-help, [bug#2464](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2464&group_id=240&atid=975) now filed to make it a graceful error. The many duplicates in i's key are making it work like a cartesion join. Can the join be done differently?

Comment: @user1935457: I am thinking that some advantage might be gained by splitting the task into two componenents: 1) firstly by creating a column [ref] in tags that references the rownumber in columns, 2) a simple select ref, max(tags) from tags group by ref, should then yield the max value per cluster. Lastly the max per cluster needs to be connected to the associated coordinate. Will work on this tonight and revert. Mean let me know if you have any thoughts on this. Cheers. Regards Nick

Comment: @user1935457, Matthew Dowle: I am thinking that some advantage might be gained by splitting the task into two componenents: 1) firstly by creating a column [ref] in tags that references the rownumber in columns, 2) a simple select ref, max(tag_count) from tags group by ref, should then yield the max value per cluster. Lastly the max per cluster needs to be connected to the associated coordinate. Will work on this tonight and revert. Mean let me know if you have any thoughts on this. Cheers. Regards Nick

Comment: @mnel: Your statement looks impressive! But am I wrong in saying that is does not capture the end coordinate from the tag table associated with the highest cluster level tag? Many thanks for your contribution! Regards Nick

Comment: @mnel: Thanks again for your contribution. R Studio crashes as before, which might be due to the memory requirements. Do you have any tips for how to accommodate that? Thanks. Nick

Comment: @NickClark I commented above but you might not have seen it. The join seems to be misspecified, similar to a cartesian join. The duplicate i key values need to be removed, or the join done differently, iiuc. Will improve `data.table` to catch the crash and also catch very large allocations due to misspecified cartesian joins.

Comment: @Matthew Dowle: Thanks. Will have a look and revert. Cheers.

Comment: @NickClark Ok, sorry for the hassle. It just happens that your first ever S.O. question is a good one and pushes data.table to the edge. Going back to @mnel's suggestion: `clusters[tags][end %between% c(start_clst, end_clst)][,.SD[which.max(tag_count)], by=list(chr, start_clst,end_clst,strand)]`, even just changing the first `][` to `,` i.e.: `clusters[tags,end %between% c(start_clst, end_clst)][,.SD[which.max(tag_count)], by=list(chr, start_clst,end_clst,strand)]` might get close (to get that first join to do `j` by row of `i`). That unlikely works, but that sort of thinking, I mean.

Comment: @Matthew Dowle. Well, short term I have gone back to SQL. Turns our properly indexing my tables moves this from days to "a mere matter of hours". Data.table looks awesome. If there way a way to manage the memory allocation directly, I'm thinking this would constitute an ideal solution. Thanks for your involvement!

Comment: @NickClark Ok no problem. I'll see if I can come up with a tested solution over the weekend ...

Comment: @ Matthew Dowle: Here is my crude solution (yet to address data.table). Used sqlite to create a table for tags and clusters with appropriate primary keys. Then inner join the two tables to find the cluster associated with each tag. All that remains is something like ddply(test, ~ ref, function(x){x[which.max(x$tags),]}) from plyr in R to find the row with the maximum tag for each cluster. Pretty it ain't , mind you. Look forward to learning more about data.table. Will keep you posted. Thanks!

Comment: @user1935457: Look interesting. Will have a look. Cheers.

Comment: @NickClark and user1935457, Have fixed the integer overflow in vecseq.c (bug #2464) and added a new argument `allow.cartesian` to prevent large allocations (commit 795 in v1.8.7). Many thanks for revealing that! But that was side issue here, iirc. How you getting on with doing the join differently?  I haven't taken a thorough look yet.

Comment: Sorry, I've been tied up with other stuff. You have not been forgotten. Will revert. Thanks again for your input. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick answer to give some hints, building on other answers and comments.

If `X[Y]` (or `merge(X,Y)`) returns a large number of rows, larger than `max(nrow(X),nrow(Y))` (such as `nrow(X)*nrow(Y)` for example) then `X[Y][where]` (i.e. `X[Y]` followed by a subset) isn't going to help. The final result is much smaller, but it has to create the large `X[Y]` first.

If ranges are required, then one way is `w = X[Y,roll=TRUE,which=TRUE]` or `w=X[Y,mult="first",which=TRUE]` or something like that, maybe twice for first and last. Once you've got row locations (`w`) of each range you can `seq` or `vecseq` between beginning and end, and then select the result.  There are some examples in other S.O. questions in this tag.  It would be nice to build this into data.table of course, and there is a feature request for it that proposes that join columns could themselves be 2 column list columns containing the bounds of the range query per row per column.

Or, *by-without-by* can be used. This is where `j` is evaluated for each row of `i` when there is no `by` clause. Search `?data.table` for by-without-by and see the examples. That's how you can stick to the cartesian-then-subset thinking, without actually creating the entire cartesian result first.  Something like:  `X[Y,.SD[start<=i.value & i.value<=end]]`.  That's probably slower than the `roll` or `mult` approach, due to the 3 vectors scans (`&`, `<=` and `<=`), though. But at least it would avoid the large memory allocation. Note that `i.` prefix can be used to refer to non join `i` columns explicitly. The `between` function in data.table could be coded in C to do that much more efficiently, similar to the `clamp` function in Rcpp. But currently `between()` is written as R vector scans, and therefore just as slow.

Hope that helps. I tried to explain the current thinking, right or wrong as it may be.

And we'll improve data.table to catch cartesian allocations with a graceful error giving some tips as mentioned in comments [EDIT: `allow.cartesian=FALSE` now added in v1.8.7].  Thanks!

---

To expand on paragraph 2 :

```
setkey(clusters,chr,strand,end_clst)
setkey(tags,chr,strand,end)

begin = tags[clusters[,list(chr,strand,start_clst)],roll=-Inf,mult="first",which=TRUE]
end = tags[clusters[,list(chr,strand,end_clst)],roll=+Inf,mult="last",which=TRUE]

idx = mapply(function(x,y){.i=seq.int(x,y); .i[ which.max(tags$tag_count[.i]) ]}, begin, end)
cbind(clusters, tags[idx])
     chr start_clst end_clst strand tags_clst  chr  start    end strand tag_count
 1: chr1     569926   569952      -        25 chr1 569942 569943      -         4
 2: chr1     713987   714049      -        46 chr1 714011 714012      -         4
 3: chr1     568911   568941      +        37 chr1 568940 568941      +         8
 4: chr1     569233   569256      +         4 chr1 569255 569256      +         2
 5: chr1     569454   569484      +         6 chr1 569471 569472      +         2
 6: chr1     569793   569803      +         3 chr1 569793 569794      +         2
 7: chr1     569877   569926      +        80 chr1 569925 569926      +         5
 8: chr1     569972   569973      +         1 chr1 569972 569973      +         1
 9: chr1     570048   570095      +         4 chr1 570048 570049      +         1
10: chr1     570166   570167      +         1 chr1 570166 570167      +         1
```

This avoids the cartsian memory allocation issue mentioned in other answers and comments. It uses the following new feature in v1.8.7 :

> o In addition to `TRUE` / `FALSE`, `roll` may now be a positive number (roll forwards/LOCF) or negative number (roll backwards/NOCB). A finite number limits the distance a value is rolled (limited staleness). `roll=TRUE` and `roll=+Inf` are equivalent.
>         `rollends` is a new parameter holding two logicals. The first observation is rolled backwards if `rollends[1]` is `TRUE`. The last observation is rolled forwards if `rollends[2]` is `TRUE`. If `roll` is a finite number, the same limit applies to the ends.

Comment: Hi Matthew. I will come back after digesting this, as I'm not a data.table expert. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one proposal using `apply`:

```
transform(
  clusters,
  start = apply(clusters[c("chr_clst", "start_clst", "end_clst", "strand_clst")],
                1, function(x) {
                     tmp <- tags[tags$start >= as.numeric(x[2]) &
                                 tags$end <= as.numeric(x[3]) & 
                                 tags$chr == x[1] & 
                                 tags$strand == x[4], c("tag_count", "start")]
                     tmp$start[which.max(tmp$tag_count)]}))
```

Basically, for each row of `clusters` the function looks for the largest value of `tag_count` inside the relevant subset of `tags`. The appropriate value in `start` is selected. These new vector of `start` values is used as a new colum for `clusters`.

The result:

```
   chr_clst start_clst end_clst strand_clst tags_clst  start
1      chr1     568911   568941           +        37 568940
2      chr1     569233   569256           +         4 569255
3      chr1     569454   569484           +         6 569471
4      chr1     569793   569803           +         3 569793
5      chr1     569877   569926           +        80 569925
6      chr1     569926   569952           -        25 569942
7      chr1     569972   569973           +         1 569972
8      chr1     570048   570095           +         4 570048
9      chr1     570166   570167           +         1 570166
10     chr1     713987   714049           -        46 714011
```

Comment: Hi Sven, thanks for doing that. My example perhaps did not properly emphasize that segments from different strands can overlap and that chr / chr_clst can take on 23 different value. Would be be possible to amend your solution accordingly? Thank again!

Comment: Thanks for doing that. I ran your modified code on a subset of the dataset. This gave the following error message in R Studio: "Error in cbind[c("chr_list", "start_clust", "end_clst", "strand_clst")] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. Any thoughts?

Comment: @NickClark Did you really use the new code? Note that there is no `cbind`.

Comment: My bad. Your code is working. Due to the size of the file, processing time is still an issue. Your solution has definitely improved on my sql-based implementatin. Thanks again for doing that!

Comment: Sven Hohenstein@: If my projections are correct the code should run for another 5.5 days. I will let you know of the outcome in any event. Thanks again. Nick

Answer (score 1):

This can be done quite efficiently using `foverlaps()` function from `data.table` which has been available since `v1.9.4`:

```
require(data.table) #v1.9.4+
setDT(clusters, key=c("chr_clst", "strand_clst", "start_clst", "end_clst"))
setDT(tags, key=c("chr", "strand", "start", "end"))

ans = foverlaps(clusters, tags)[, .SD[which.max(tag_count)], by=.(chr_clst, strand_clst, start_clst, end_clst)]

#     chr_clst strand_clst start_clst end_clst  start    end tag_count tags_clst
#  1:     chr1           -     569926   569952 569942 569943         4        25
#  2:     chr1           -     713987   714049 714011 714012         4        46
#  3:     chr1           +     568911   568941 568940 568941         8        37
#  4:     chr1           +     569233   569256 569255 569256         2         4
#  5:     chr1           +     569454   569484 569471 569472         2         6
#  6:     chr1           +     569793   569803 569793 569794         2         3
#  7:     chr1           +     569877   569926 569925 569926         5        80
#  8:     chr1           +     569972   569973 569972 569973         1         1
#  9:     chr1           +     570048   570095 570048 570049         1         4
# 10:     chr1           +     570166   570167 570166 570167         1         1
```

`foverlaps()` will also eventually be able to perform overlapping range joins without having to *key* them first, similar to the new `on=` (v1.9.6+) argument.